Has NASA published any information that better quantifies the mass budget requirements for "back to the moon ... this time to stay"?
I'm interested in those elements of their plans that will help me to estimate a yearly mass budget, such as how many crew at a time, how long will they stay each time, how often they will be rotated out, and what kinds of facilities they plan to set up on the moon.

The latest stuff is here but there is a high BS to data ratio. https://www.nasa.gov/moontomarsarchitecture-architecturedefinitiondocuments/ If you look at the executive summary, there is a listing of "white papers" that have more detail on logistics, etc but still pretty hand-wavey.
